# 'Object Does Not Contain a Definition For 'TextShown'.....' error

Tags: c#, ssis

I've hit an issue with a piece of code that I'm repurposing and learning from that I hope the community can help me out with.

Here's the full codeset;

I'm getting errors returned complaining about "'object' does not contain a definition for 'TextShown'". Any assistance in the correct declaration formatting is greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Text;
/// <summary>
/// This is the class to which to add your code.  Do not change the name, attributes, or parent
/// of this class.
/// </summary>
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private OleDbConnection connection;
    private OleDbCommand command;
    private OleDbDataReader reader;

    public object NumbersandTextBuffer { get; set; }

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();

        connection = new OleDbConnection(Connections.DataSourceConnection.ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;

        // Build select query by iterating over the columns in first output collection
        var query = new StringBuilder("SELECT ");
        var outputCollection = ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < outputCollection.OutputColumnCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            query.AppendFormat(" [{0}]", outputCollection.OutputColumnCollection[i].Name);
            if (i < outputCollection.OutputColumnCollection.Count - 1) query.Append(",");
        }

        query.AppendFormat(" FROM [{0}]", outputCollection.Name);

        command.CommandText = query.ToString();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();

        command = null;
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Replace with own import code matching the name
            // of the import buffer defined in the Script Transformation Editor
            // and column names
            NumbersandTextBuffer.AddRow();

            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["AgencyLongName"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["AgencyShortName"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["ProjectID"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["CollectionRound"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["Section"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["TableType"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["Metric"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["Section1"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["BenefitID"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["RiskID"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["Value"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["F12"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["F13"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["F14"];
            NumbersandTextBuffer.TextShown = (string)reader["F15"];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you declared `NumbersandTextBuffer` as Object and `System.Object` has no such method.  it is also not an array or collection but it looks like you are treating it as such anyway. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: It also doesn't have a method called `AddRow()`.

Comment: Thanks for the insights and help. I removed the Object and corrected a type with the input buffer for NumbersAndText, added the Addrow() and its now working